# Web resources for specific types of funny pictures?

Tags: webapp-rec, images

*No, not lolcats. And I'm not really looking for a specific site, either.*

I have often wished that I had some funny picture to illustrate a presentation, a website, a post, an email, or something else. Google image search and stock photo services have hardly ever helped me, although that may be because I'm doing something wrong.

Jeff Atwood seems to have no problem to find funny pictures for his [codinghorror](http://www.codinghorror.com/) and [stackoverflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/) blogs, as well as for the error messages on the trilogy sites. One of my favorites was [this elephant](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001224.html). Other bloggers also seem to be quite good at it.

I'm wondering if I simply lack the creativity or if there's sources or methods I don't know about. I could think of the following ways to get pictures, but I'm not sure whether this is really "how they do it".

- keep a collection of pictures that you stumbled upon and liked (takes quite some time to build up to a proper library) when you need a picture, there's one in there
- maybe have pictures on paper, too, like from magazines or ads.
- when you are looking for a picture, search online (Flickr, Google, stock photos). This has never really worked for me, I don't know why.
- produce the pictures yourself, i. e. have a good library of source material or find some online and apply some creativity and suitable software. I could imagine that this could work well once you have the practice.

Comment: We need more people adding description to funny images so that people can google them easily. You come across a good picture and you talk about that picture and write its description on your metablog. You come across a funny picture from reddit or digg, you add a comment describing that image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best method: sign up with [StumbleUpon.com](https://www.stumbleupon.com/) and install the toolbar. Set your preference to humor related categories. SU is the best when it comes to finding the quality content of your taste.
But beware, it's very very addictive.

There are other blog sites(typical Tumblr blogs) that metablog most current funny photos. Here's a list that I frequent:

- http://icanhascheezburger.com/
- http://www.9gag.com
- http://www.reddit.com
- http://thedw.us/
- http://thisisindexed.com/

These blogs often link to sites they metablog from, and you can discover even more from there.

All that said, let me warn you. Looking for funny pictures on the internet can lead to long-term addiction, trust me, I know. You'll be hopping from one site to the next, and share them with your buddy on aim, Skype, Twitter etc. Eventually, you'll start your own Tumblr to meta-blog these even further.... and next thing you know, you're going to bed at 4 am every night.

The end.

Answer (score 1):

I think [4chan](http://www.4chan.org/) has a lot of funny pictures.

*Warning: NSFW images could also be found there.*

Comment: Definition of "funny" is obviously something "user-specific"

Comment: I firmly believe 4chan has something everybody will find funny, it's just whether you're willing to go through the 99.9% of things that range from unfunny to disgusting.

Comment: It's basically the same recycled jokes, pictures, threads and copied posts day in day out every day of the year.

Comment: Jonno_FTW, just don't access the same board every day, then.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not exactly what you are looking for, but VERY funny!

http://failblog.org/

Also a stock image site will have lots of (funny and not funny) images at a small price per image or a subscription.

Comment: I just recommended http://icanhascheezburger.com/, and it seems to be the same as failblog.org. LOLZ!

Answer (score 0):

Today it's not only LOL Cats but all kinds of funny pics:
http://icanhascheezburger.com/
Go through the blue bar at the top for different categories.
LOLZ!

Answer (score 0):

Nobody mentioned [b3ta](http://b3ta.com/) yet? OK, so it's not for everyone, but I think that there *is* something for everyone. Ranging from the smug, the in-joke and the pure silly, to the clever, hilarious, satirical, daring, ... It's frequently NSFW, or NSFanything, and the quality can vary. But it is often a source of what you're looking for, and it's users/contributors have been responsible for plenty of those "have you seen this yet?" internet buzzes.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't aware, there is the funny and pics subreddit on Reddit:

http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/
http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/

Funny isn't usually pictures but it is pretty good.

Have an interest? There's a subreddit for that!